# Python - Problem multiplying the inverse of a matrix with a vector - Structural Engineering (FEM)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, matrix-inverse

I´m developing a code to analyse portal frames with the finite element method.
However I´m encountering a problem, when I try to multiply the inverse of specic positions of a matrix with an array, Python is returning: shapes (9,9) and (9,1,1) not aligned: 9 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 1).
I have a 15x15 matrix and an array with 15 rows, but I just need to multiply positions [3:11].
Any guess where the problem might be?

The code is too big to be displayed in SO, so I just wrighted the 15x15 matrix, kportico, and the array, f. I´ve allready checked the matrix and the array and they are correct.

```
k = [k1global, k2global, k3global, k4global]

kportico = np.zeros([15, 15])

for i, m in enumerate(k):
    kportico[i*3:i*3+6, i*3:i*3+6] += m

f = np.array([[f1global[0]],
              [f1global[1]],
              [f1global[2]],
              [f1global[3]+f2globalx[0]+f2globaly[0]],
              [f1global[4]+f2globalx[1]+f2globaly[1]],
              [f1global[5]+f2globalx[2]+f2globaly[2]],
              [f2globalx[3]+f2globaly[3]+f3globalx[0]+f3globaly[0]],
              [f2globalx[4]+f2globaly[4]+f3globalx[1]+f3globaly[1]],
              [f2globalx[5]+f2globaly[5]+f3globalx[2]+f3globaly[2]],
              [f4global[3]+f3globalx[3]+f3globaly[3]],
              [f4global[4]+f3globalx[4]+f3globaly[4]],
              [f4global[5]+f3globalx[5]+f3globaly[5]],
              [f4global[0]],
              [f4global[1]],
              [f4global[2]]])

u = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(kportico[np.ix_([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])]), f[np.ix_([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])])
```

Comment: `np.dot` is clear about how the dimensions of the arguments have to match. A (9,9) will work with a (9,) or (9,1), but not a (9,1,1).

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I don´t know what I did for the code assume (9,1,1) instead of (9,1).

Comment: What is `f`, (15,1) or (15,1,1)?

Comment: f is supose to be (15,1)

Comment: `suposed` isn't the same as `is`